# WebStorm can not find module after installing TypeScript community stubs

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

I am trying to use a library `ramda` and have installed its TypeScript community stubs in WebStorm —

[image: Ramda Stub]

but I am still getting the following error —

```
Cannot find module 'ramda'.
```

[image: Error message]

I know I can solve this problem using the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) module but then what's the point of installing the stubs via WebStorm then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries configured in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries` are *only used by WebStorm for code completion/navigation, but they aren't available to TypeScript compiler*.

When you download Typescript stubs via `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, they are placed in `<webStorm configuration directory>/javascript/extLibs/`. It's perfectly fine for WebStorm - it doesn't require placing library files directly in the project folder, as the main purpose of libraries is the ability to use external files for code completion without polluting the project folder. But the tsc compiler does need the d.ts files being placed somewhere in the project directory and referenced via `///<reference>` comments/import statements.

So, to get downloaded stubs available to typescript compiler, you need to copy/move them to you project directory (and probably rename to more human readable names :)) They will be available to both WebStorm and compiler then.

We plan to provide an option to download files directly to the project folder (instead of `system/extLibs/` ) in the future versions - see [WEB-9237](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9237) and linked tickets.